# MYSQL query to find amount of services reviewed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

My database has the following tables.

```
services

+----+----------+

| id |serviceID | 

+----+----------+

reviews

+----+----------+-----------+

| id | reviewID | serviceID |

+----+----------+-----------+
```

these link together on the `serviceID`.

Now i want to be able to get the amount of services reviewed.

So there could be like 5000 reviews but all those reviews where on 13 services for example.

How would i achieve this in MYSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Total amount of services being reviewed:

```
SELECT count(distinct serviceID) FROM reviews
```

Comment: thanks thats great thanks, do you know how i could get this amount based on a between statement. meaning count them from reviews where the reviews where `created_at` between two dates?

Comment: Just add WHERE created_at  > '<Your_date1>' AND created_at  < '<Your_date2>' condition to that query.

Comment: @skorchakov but there is no `created_at` column according to database schema provided ;-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to get how many different services have been reviewed.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews GROUP BY serviceID
```

Comment: With this query you would get how many services have been reviewed in total. If you have 3 services A, B and C and A received no eviews, B received 35 reviews and C received 70 reviews this query would return 2.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `select count(*)` on `reviews` grouped by `serviceID` should give you that:

```
SELECT count(*), serviceID 
FROM reviews 
GROUP BY serviceID
```

This will give you how many reviews you had for each service.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need the number of services that have at least one review. To find it you can use this code:

```
select count(*) from services s
where EXISTS
select * from reviews r where r.serviceID = s.serviceID
```